# Unity3D static splash image scalling options not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Unity3D Version: 2018.4.8c3 (2018.4.16f1 same problem)

I am trying to make a static, full screen splash image for Unity3D Android app. however, I found that the splash image could not scal/resize properly on different resolution android phones.
Unity Doc says three different kinds of scalling [unity doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidMobileCustomizeSplashScreen.html?_ga=2.222032984.1151247312.1581055880-250153184.1570517738):

Center (only scale down) draws your image at its natural size unless it is too large, in which case it is scaled down to fit.

Scale to fit (letter-boxed) draws your image so that the longer dimension fits the screen size exactly. **Empty space around the sides in the shorter dimension is filled in black.**

Scale to fill (cropped) scales your image so that the shorter dimension fits the screen size exactly. The image is cropped in the longer dimension.

In my Player settings:
[image]

the splash sprite is 720*1440 resolution.
But when I runs it on 2080*2340 phones, ends up like this

[image]

I know the splash image is white and not proper scalling results blank gaps that looks augly.
Changing scalling setting does not shown change after build. I find there must be a scalling method taking the screen size into account. Different notch on android phones results in difference scalling looking.

what's the proper way making a full screen splash for all android devices? what's a optimal size for splash image?
Thanks

Comment: Might be worth reporting as issue on Unity forums. Also, might see if the following advice for a similar issue works https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/138345/how-to-fix-stretched-splash-image-in-unity Change the rect type prop on the textures setting to full rect.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is wrong attribute in final apk AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
```

You could just drag and drop the apk to Android Studio, then check AndroidManifest.xml.

You should change it to 2, which represent 'Scale to fill (cropped)':

```
<meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="2" />
```

Maybe your build process is modified by PostProcessor or something else, then the attribute is replaced to 0.